# Software for arranging logical gates

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for a software that is capable of arranging the logical gates based on a set of input values, and the desired output results.

The complexity of the logical gates should not be limited to simple solutions.

So far I am not sure if such software exists, so anything similar would be also a good recommendation.

Comment: If it is of any interest there was a research project that used evolutionary testing to program a PLA to attempt to design a logic circuit - it worked but it turned out the design was not transferable to any other chip. Some information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolvable_hardware

Comment: @SteveBarnes yes, pointing to a topic does help a lot!  Do you know any direct links for such software (commercial or non-commercial) ? I do not need to transfer it to a hardware, as long as it can be emulated.

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6175116&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4235%2F4358751%2F06175116.pdf%3Farnumber%3D6175116 gives a nice case study.

Answer (score 3):

I think this website (not a downloadable software) is similar to what you're asking. This is more of a digital IC trainer kit simulator.
Been a long time since you've asked. Check it out if it is of any help now.

https://www.deldsim.com/simulator/

Comment: That web-app is great fun and is very useful.  Thank you for posting it all these years later!

Comment: Thank you, I am still interested in a topic and will be checking the link shortly. I hope they can auto-arrange the logic gates rather than provide only an interface to connections...

Comment: @DamirOlejar, I don't think it can auto arrange logic gates. It's mostly working with ICs as a whole to build different combinational and sequential circuits.